# What does the 1/2 means in the L1 or L2 formula

Tags: regression

[image]

May I ask what does the 1/2 means in this formula for lasso. I searched formula examples for lasso and ridge. And found sometimes there is 1/2 while sometimes no.

Comment: It's just a constant which simplifies the equation down the road, it has no special meaning.

Comment: Oh, get it. Thank you @user2974951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there to cancel out the 2 from the power when you take the derivative. It's just for convenience thought, you can do it without it, but the math will look a bit uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, 1/2 is used in front of the MSE term or the square-regularisation terms, just to make the subsequent analysis more intuitive. The corresponding regularisation coefficient, $\lambda$, will be different but 1-1.